# In RHEL, can you associate the GID of an AD group with the GID of a local group?

Tags: networking, rhel, windows, active-directory

I have a Windows Active Directory system and the GID of group X is 1745005454. The RHEL machines are AD joined using realm and SSSD authenticated, and when you do an `id username` it will show that that user is in group X of 1745005454.

However, several different environments exist and are not connected to each other and have this similar setup and the GID on each environment for group X is different. This causes issues on the RHEL systems on all environments where there are local group X's all with the consistent GID of 10001 and scripts being executed that look for the 10001 GID in order to run.

There are no local users (except for root and local admin accounts), and I can't add the AD user to the local group obviously. I can't change the GID of the AD group X to the needed 10001, so the question is.... can I configure RHEL to see the incoming group X GID 1745005454 (or whatever) and make it associate/alias to the local GID 10001 for group X and being equivalent?

Comment: Will official documentation help?
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-configuring_authentication#doc-wrapper

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation that would point to the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not supported. You can change the GID of the AD group if you want using sss_override but the GID and the group name cannot match a local GID/group name (this is called group collision).

7.6. SSSD Client-side Views
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/sssd-client-side-views

So by installing sssd-tools, and using "*sss_override group-add X -g 10001*" I can add the group X to an sssd override mapping that will change the incoming GID of group X from AD and change it to the needed GID of 10001.